# Nutch - Lucene - capture the content of the pages

Tags: lucene, nutch, web-crawler

I have crawled a few pages with Java Nutch
Also I  have made a module with Lucene in Java which allows execute queries on indexed documents.
I know I created Nutch fields like url, weight and the title. But I am interested in capturing the content of each page. How I can do it using Lucene and knowing I have crawled with nutch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details about what you want to achieve... because Nutch already includes a Lucene Index so I wonder why you want another one????
Nutch has a jsp front-end where you can look at, and find how to query for some field content. There is a cache system implemented so you can retrieve the cached data of page, but then you have to parse it again and index it again.

Comment: I have crawled news of diferents sites, using java Nutch

I need to retrieve the html content of these pages because I have to create documents. These documents have to save the content of each new.

These documents will be used to clasify these news using the java api MAPLES. 

I will use Lucene to manage these documents.

Thanks.

Comment: Nutch is not a document database, it really is geared towards search, crawling is one part of it. At search time you can retrieve the html of the document as I explained (look at cached.jsp for how you can do that). However you may want to manage your document within Nutch rather then outside... or find another crawler.